# writing a Class with method returning same Class object

Tags: haskell

I am writing a chat server in haskell. Earlier i had tcp sockets. Now i am moving to WebSockets. I wanted to create a thin wrapper of `NetworkConn` over it.. I am having problem writing `accept` function.

`acceptReuqest PendingConnection` returns `Connection`

and

`fst <$> accept Socket` is `Socket`.

So, i tried following ..
Creating `NetworkConn` for `Socket, Connection, PendingConnection`

```
class NetworkConn sock where
  accept :: (NetworkConn myconn) => sock -> IO myconn

instance NetworkConn NS.Socket where
  accept sock    = fst <$> NS.accept sock

instance NetworkConn WS.Connection where
  accept sock    = error "Not allowed"
```

`acceptReuqest PendingConnection` returns `Connection`

```
instance NetworkConn WS.PendingConnection where
  accept sock = WS.acceptRequest sock
```

This gives me error in `NS.Socket` that

```
Couldn't match type ‘myconn’ with ‘NS.Socket’
      ‘myconn’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for
                 acceptC :: NetworkConn myconn => NS.Socket -> IO myconn
               at src/HChat/Network.hs:21:3
    Expected type: IO
                     (myconn, network-2.6.2.1:Network.Socket.Types.SockAddr)
      Actual type: IO
                     (NS.Socket, network-2.6.2.1:Network.Socket.Types.SockAddr)
    Relevant bindings include
      acceptC :: NS.Socket -> IO myconn
        (bound at src/HChat/Network.hs:21:3)
    In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘NS.accept sock’
    In the expression: fst <$> NS.accept sock
```

and

```
Couldn't match type ‘myconn’ with ‘WS.Connection’
      ‘myconn’ is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for
                 acceptC :: NetworkConn myconn => WS.PendingConnection -> IO myconn
               at src/HChat/Network.hs:31:3
    Expected type: IO myconn
      Actual type: IO WS.Connection
    Relevant bindings include
      acceptC :: WS.PendingConnection -> IO myconn
        (bound at src/HChat/Network.hs:31:3)
```

I starting reading about `class` and could not understand why the error is coming.
I guess it is a syntactic error, but unable to figure it out. Please help.

Also Is it possible to restrict the return type to be NetworkConn because i only want to call few methods defined only in NetworkConn.. ?

Trying two classes:

```
class CandidateConn c where
  acceptC :: (NetworkConn s) => c -> IO s

class NetworkConn sock where
  send :: sock -> C.ByteString -> IO ()
  recv :: sock -> IO C.ByteString
  accept :: (CandidateConn conn) => conn -> IO sock

instance NetworkConn NS.Socket where
  send sock text = void $ NSB.send sock text
  recv sock      = NSB.recv sock 1024
  accept c       = acceptC c

instance CandidateConn NS.Socket where
  acceptC sock = fst <$> NS.accept sock
```

gives :

```
Couldn't match type ‘s’ with ‘NS.Socket’
      ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            acceptC :: NetworkConn s => NS.Socket -> IO s
          at src/HChat/Network.hs:29:3
    Expected type: IO
                     (s, network-2.6.2.1:Network.Socket.Types.SockAddr)
      Actual type: IO
                     (NS.Socket, network-2.6.2.1:Network.Socket.Types.SockAddr)
    Relevant bindings include
      acceptC :: NS.Socket -> IO s (bound at src/HChat/Network.hs:29:3)
```

Comment: The problem with your definition is that `accept` can get *any* type of class NetworkConn and return *any other* type of class NetworkConn. You either want it to (1) always return the same constant type, or (2) always return the input type or (3) return a type that *depends on* input type. For 3, have a multipatameter type class `NetworkConn a b where accept :: a->b` and constrain it with fundep, or use a type family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type signature:

```
class NetworkConn sock where
  accept :: (NetworkConn myconn) => sock -> IO myconn
```

says, "a type `sock` that is a `NetworkConn` provides a function `accept` that takes a `sock` and returns an action resulting in whatever type the caller requires, as long as that type in turn is a `NetworkConn`."

This is a promise you cannot uphold. You probably wanted to write that it returns "some type specific to `sock` that also implements `NetworkConn`". That's what associated types are for.

Roughly speaking, you enable the TypeFamilies extension and then write

```
class NetworkConn sock where
  type AcceptedConn sock :: *
  accept :: sock -> IO (AcceptedConn sock)
```

except this lacks the `NetworkConn` constraint for `AcceptedConn`. I have trouble finding the right syntax to express this and can't syntax-check at the moment, but you can try this:

```
class NetworkConn (AcceptedConn sock) => NetworkConn sock where
  type AcceptedConn sock :: *
  accept :: sock -> IO (AcceptedConn sock)
```

I think this requires FlexibleInstances to be enabled.

The instance declaration then becomes:

```
instance NetworkConn WS.PendingConnection where
  type AcceptedConn WS.PendingConnection = Connection
  accept sock = WS.acceptRequest sock
```

As I said, I have not done syntax checking on this at all.

Comment: this answer is right for what i asked.. but i have `send` and `recv` method that needs `Connection` at which case, this fails.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
class NetworkConn sock where
  accept :: sock -> IO sock
```

What you wrote was a universal return type, whereas I reckon your `accept` methods only return specific connection types.

If you do want a dynamic return, you might need 2 type classes like

```
class CandidateConn sock where
  -- some methods
class NetworkConn sock where
  accept :: CandidateConn c => c -> IO sock
```

Comment: `acceptReuqest PendingConnection` returns `Connection` so i had to keep the return type different.. i have edited the question.. apologies for that being not visible before.

Comment: Is it possible to restrict the return type to be `NetworkConn` because i only want to call few methods defined only in `NetworkConn`.. ?

Comment: The return is restricted to NetworkConn in the 2-class solution above

Comment: i have updated the question with  your approach.. since c is of type `CandidateConn` i can only call functions defined in that `CandidateConn`.. Now the errors have moved to CandidateConn.. did i fail to understand your approach ?

Answer (score 1):

A noble soul `{As}` on #haskell irc channel suggested to use https://wiki.haskell.org/Multi-parameter_type_class

and it worked.. thanks `{As}`

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

module HChat.Network where

-- For Network.Socket library
import qualified Network.Socket as NS (Socket, accept)
import qualified Network.Socket.ByteString as NSB (send, recv)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

-- For WebSockets library
import qualified Network.WebSockets as WS

import Control.Monad (void)

class NetworkConn sock conn where
  send :: conn -> C.ByteString -> IO ()
  recv :: conn -> IO C.ByteString
  accept :: sock -> IO conn

instance NetworkConn NS.Socket NS.Socket where
  send conn text = void $ NSB.send conn text
  recv conn      = NSB.recv conn 1024
  accept sock    = fst <$> NS.accept sock

instance NetworkConn WS.PendingConnection WS.Connection where
  send sock text = WS.sendTextData sock text
  recv sock      = WS.receiveData sock
  accept sock    = WS.acceptRequest sock
```